# How to explicitly define Apache Camel CXF Consumer and Producer

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am experiencing an interesting dilemma with Apache Camel and CXF.

I try to build following routes.

`from("servlet://proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE");`

```
`from("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE").to("file:/META-INF/data/test.xml");`
```

My wish actually is to receive the request with Servlet Component, do something with (processor, transform, etc but I excluded here for simplicity reasons) redirect this to my WebService implementation and the file component return the content of a file as a result to WebService.

The problem is, if I make from Endpoint '`from("servlet://proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")`' routing to Endpoint '`to("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")`' Camel thinks this should be CXF Consumer but I want it to be a Producer.

So I actually I like to route from `from("servlet://proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")` to '`from("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")`' but I could not figure out a way to do it.

If I configure as the first configuration, the servlet component receives the request, routes to CXF:consumer then it starts a TCP call to CXF:Producer defined in '`from("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")`' it works but it is weird, I don't want to start a TCP call, I just want that the message goes to '`from("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")`'.

Is there a way to achieve what I want? Can I define a CXF Consumer or Provider other then using 'from', 'to'?

Funnily I did something similar with ServiceMix/Fuse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:osgiRouter="http://osgi.salgar.org/osgirouter"
    xmlns:http="http://servicemix.apache.org/http/1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://servicemix.apache.org/http/1.0 http://servicemix.apache.org/http/1.0/servicemix-http.xsd">

    <http:consumer service="http:FindOrders" endpoint="httpEndpoint" locationURI="http://localhost:8088/MockB2BService"
        defaultMep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out" targetService="osgiRouter:mediation"  />

    <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.common.osgi.EndpointExporter" />
</beans>
```

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:eip="http://servicemix.apache.org/eip/1.0"
    xmlns:osgiRouter="http://osgi.salgar.org/osgirouter"
    xmlns:orderProvider_v1="http://v1.salgar.org/B2BService"
    xmlns:orderProvider_v2="http://v2.salgar.org/B2BService"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://servicemix.apache.org/eip/1.0 http://servicemix.apache.org/eip/1.0/servicemix-eip.xsd">

    <eip:content-based-router endpoint="osgiRouterMediation"
        service="osgiRouter:mediation">
        <eip:rules>
            <eip:routing-rule>
                <eip:predicate>
                    <eip:xpath-predicate id="wsdl_version_predicate_v1"
                        xpath="(//namespace::*[.='http://v1.salgar.org/B2BService']) = 'http://v1.salgar.org/B2BService'" />
                </eip:predicate>
                <eip:target>
                    <eip:exchange-target service="orderProvider_v1:findOrders" />
                </eip:target>
            </eip:routing-rule>
            <eip:routing-rule>
                <eip:predicate>
                    <eip:xpath-predicate id="wsdl_version_predicate_v2"
                        xpath="(//namespace::*[.='http://v2.salgar.org/B2BService']) = 'http://v2.salgar.org/B2BService'" />
                </eip:predicate>
                <eip:target>
                    <eip:exchange-target service="orderProvider_v2:findOrders" />
                </eip:target>
            </eip:routing-rule>
        </eip:rules>
    </eip:content-based-router>

    <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.common.osgi.EndpointExporter" />
</beans>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cxfbc="http://servicemix.apache.org/cxfbc/1.0"
    xmlns:orderProvider_v1="http://v1.salgar.org/B2BService"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://servicemix.apache.org/cxfbc/1.0 http://servicemix.apache.org/cxfbc/1.0/servicemix-cxf-bc.xsd">
    <cxfbc:provider endpoint="findOrdersProviderEndpoint"
        useJBIWrapper="false" wsdl="classpath:v1/B2BService.wsdl" service="orderProvider_v1:findOrders"
        locationURI="http://localhost:8989/MockB2BService" />

    <bean class="org.apache.servicemix.common.osgi.EndpointExporter" />
</beans>
```

Which works as expected but there I could define the endpoint explicitly as CXF provider, do I have the same possibility here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, this will work (and ideal solution in camel)

Route A

```
from("servlet://proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("direct:webservice-business-logic")
.to("direct:process-to-file");
```

Route B

```
from("direct:webservice-business-logic")
.to("actual-processors-to-do-webservice-business-logic");
```

Route C

```
from("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
.to("direct:webservice-business-logic);
```

Basically, Route C will be used only by external parties who wants to use the webservice.

Route B will be used only by Route A, So Route B is meant for Internal camel processing. Because there is no point in calling a webservice , where the webservice logic also sits in the camel route.

Hope this helps !

Comment: if I use 'from("servlet://proxy?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
.to("file:/META-INF/data/test.xml");` and 'to("cxf:/incident?wsdlURL=wsdl/OrderInfoService.wsdl&dataFormat=MESSAGE")' tries to consume a webservice (makes a TCP call) not produce it(provide the implementation logic of the webservice). At least it is working this way in my test rig.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear, but I have updated the answer. Hope it helps. Let me know if it is still not helping.

Comment: Unfortunately my use case is much more weird. You are making the assumption to call web service internally does not make any sense but I want that, when I got the call from servlet endpoint and route to web service endpoint I still want that wsdl conformity checked and additionally I have some web server headers in the call they should be also interpreted at Web Service endpoint.  So I will need an internal web service endpoint.

Comment: Okay, tell me this , the business logic for the web service also sits in the camel routes right ? Also can you correct my assumptions ? Either ways it looks like an interesting problem , let's see if we can solve it

Comment: Yeah, business logic lies in Camel routes also, in this case it is simple as loading a xml file. I don't know what can I write more. My use case is practically having 'a servlet endpoint' receiving the request,  do some processing with request then route it to 'a cxf endpoint' which should be reachable without a TCP call (so I want a CXF producer endpoint not a consumer) and 'CXF endpoint' will produce it content reading a file from adirectory. Servicemix/Fuse route that I also placed above does exactly this and works, may be it is more expressive here then my explanation tries with words

Comment: Only assumption I can correct, you think nobody will want to call a CXF producer from inside of a route but only externally. Well that exactly what I to do, call a CXF producer from another internal route.